# Lint tags project_id generated by google services plugin as UnusedResource

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, lint, android-lint

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin), the Google Services Plugin generates XML files that can be referenced in code. My problem is that when running the `lintRelease` task for my Android project, lint tags a resource found in one of the XMLs generated by the said plugin as unused. It incorrectly tags `project_id` found in `build/generated/res/google-services/release/values/values.xml` and throws an `UnusedResources` error. Any idea how to fix this? My `lintOptions` in my build.gradle look like this:

```
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("${rootDir}/lint.xml")
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        absolutePaths false
        warningsAsErrors true
        abortOnError true
        checkGeneratedSources true
        ignoreTestSources true
        checkDependencies true
        disable "LintBaseline", "InvalidPackage", "ObsoleteLintCustomCheck", "RtlHardcoded"
    }
```

My `lint.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="InvalidPackage" >
        <ignore path="**/sentry*.jar"/>
    </issue>

    <issue id="all" >
        <ignore path="*/common/testbase"/>
    </issue>

    <issue id="RestrictedApi" severity="error">
        <ignore path="build" />
    </issue>

</lint>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I just added the `UnusedResources` issue on my `lint.xml` like this:

```
    <issue id="UnusedResources" severity="error">
        <ignore path="build" />
    </issue>
```